# Java - Mersenne Prime assignment

Tags: java

the assignment is to find all Mersenne primes with p <= 31 and display in a table:

```
p     2^p-1
---   ---- 
2      3

3      7

5      31

...
```

My result so far is this code:

```
public class PE28MersennePrimeVer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("p\t2^p - 1");

        for (int number = 2; number <= 31; number++) {
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                int mersennePrime = (int)(Math.pow(2, number)) - 1;
                if (isPrime(mersennePrime)) {
                    System.out.print(number + "\t" + mersennePrime + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {

        if ((number == 1) || (number == 2)) {
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= number/2; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The output is for p up to 19, never reach 31. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you have very strange prime checking algorithm. You should check up to sqrt(number) not up to number/2

Comment: what's a mersenne prime?

Comment: @SamIam: Did you try googling?  There's an entire website dedicated to Mersenne Primes (http://www.mersenne.org/), and wikipedia and MathWorld both have information about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
(int)Math.pow(2,31) - 1;
```

evaluates to 2147483646 instead of 2147483647.

Don't use floating point math when dealing with integers. In Java, using `(1 << number) - 1` works (`1 << 31` would be undefined behaviour in C due to overflow, but it's defined in Java).

If you cannot use bit-shifts, you can write your own integer-power function. For the small exponents under consideration, the straightforward

```
long pow(long base, long exponent) {
    long result = 1;
    while(exponent > 0) {
        result *= base;
        --exponent;
    }
}
```

is good enough (note: I used `long` instead of `int` to avoid overflows; although the overflow behaviour is defined in Java, avoiding overflow is cleaner).

With that,

```
mersennePrime = (int)(pow(2,number) - 1);
```

does its job (although you should consider using `long` also for the other variables, not only for the intermediate `pow` result).

For larger exponents (although that would only be relevant for using `BigInteger`s - which have their own implementation in the standard library - or modular exponentiation), exponentiation by repeated squaring

```
long pow(long base, long exponent) {
    long aux = 1;
    while(exponent > 0) {
        if (exponent % 2 == 1) {
            aux *= base;
        }
        base *= base;
        exponent /= 2;
    }
    return aux;
}
```

would give a big performance advantage.

Comment: I'm still at the beginning of the book (at Chapter 5 Methods) and it is supposed to write the code as much as the material covered by the book so far. I've tried with (long)(Math.pow(2, number) with no success also

Comment: No don't know how to work with them, I'm looking for this bit-shifts on Google now, but it is not supposed to use them, though
Thank you for your help

Comment: @venta7 I added a simple (and a less simple) integer power function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this for me. I've just realized that there is still a looooot to learn to have this kind of thinking